# Type Error: List Indices must be integers, not str. While adding strs to CSV

Tags: python, csv

Not sure what about this is wrong. Trying to import a line, which is joined as a string, and then put that in a CSV... Hmm....

```
import csv
import io
import os
import sys

def putInCSV():
    if os.stat("test_attacking_ips_spreadsheet.csv").st_size == 0:
        temp = open("test_attacking_ips_spreadsheet.csv", 'wb')
        tempwrite = csv.writer(temp)
        tempwrite.writerow(["IP Address"]['Hostname']['AS Number']['AS Name']['Net Range']['CC']['Type']['Targets']['Last Seen']['Notes']['FW Block']['Signatures'])
        #["IP Address"]['Hostname']['AS Number']['AS Name']['Net Range']['CC']['Type']['Targets']['Last Seen']['Notes']['FW Block']['Signatures']#
        temp.close()
    Read = open("test_attacking_ips_spreadsheet.csv", 'rb')
    Append = open("test_attacking_ips_spreadsheet.csv", 'ab')
    reader = csv.reader(Read)
    writer = csv.writer(Append)
    sweetness = len(list(reader))
    fileName = ''.join(sys.argv[1:2])
    if fileName == '':
        fileName = raw_input('Input the file with extension\n>')
    with open(fileName) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = ''.join(line)
            if "|" in line:
                findStop = line.index("|")
                ASNum = line[:findStop]
                if "-" not in ASNum:
                    ASLine = "AS" + ASNum
                else:
                    ASLine = ''
                remainder = line[findStop:]
                findStop = remainder.index("|")
                ipAdd = remainder[:findStop]
                HSTNm = ''
                remainder = line[findStop:]
                findStop = remainder.index("|")
                ASName = remainder[:findStop]

                writer.writerow([ipAdd][HSTNm][ASLine][ASName])

putInCSV()
```

Anyone see my fault? I couldn't find a concise reason, as most people linked api info, but, I couldn't find info to help back up my research.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\bulk_whois\PutInCSV.py", line 46, in <module>

    putInCSV()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\bulk_whois\PutInCSV.py", line 44, in putInCSV

    writer.writerow([ipAdd][HSTNm][ASLine][ASName])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are plain wrong:

```
tempwrite.writerow(["IP Address"]['Hostname']['AS Number']['AS Name']['Net Range']['CC']['Type']['Targets']['Last Seen']['Notes']['FW Block']['Signatures'])
...
writer.writerow([ipAdd][HSTNm][ASLine][ASName])
```

The syntax to define a list is `l = ["a", "b", "c"]`

`["IP Address"]['Hostname']` tries to extract the element of index `'Hostname'` from the list `["IP Address"]` and leads to your error.